# Getting error code 1064 for SELECT statement in MySQL Workbench. Unsure why

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

Just started MySQL class using Murach's MySQL 2nd Edition. Using MySQL Workbench, I 'm getting a 1064 error code for a `SELECT` statement I am trying to perform. I'm stumped. Here is my `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT item_id, item_price, discount_amount,
       quantity * item_price AS price_total,
       quantity * discount_amount AS discount_total,
       price_total - discount_total AS item_total
FROM order_items
ORDER BY item_total DESC
WHERE  item_total > 500
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided your database schema, but 1064 is a syntax error and I can see why that's happening. Your `WHERE` clause has to precede your `ORDER BY` clause like this...

```
SELECT item_id, item_price, discount_amount,
       quantity * item_price AS price_total,
       quantity * discount_amount AS discount_total,
       price_total - discount_total AS item_total
FROM order_items
WHERE item_total > 500
ORDER BY item_total DESC
```